# Should I pay google maps to make GPS coordinates requests in android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, gps, google-geolocation

My goal is to get latitude & longitude every 5 seconds.

I have already archived that in my app by adding ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest and by creating a LocationManager instance and then implementing LocationListener to get the coordinates.

Now for no obvious reason I stopped getting results from onLocationChanged function and I get this CancellationException error:

```
E/RequestManagerImpl: Producing location failed
                                                  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
                                                      at dagger.producers.Produced$Failed.get(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.cy.j.ac.a(SourceFile:98)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.cy.j.am.aH(SourceFile:11)
                                                      at dagger.producers.internal.AbstractProducesMethodProducer.aD(SourceFile:11)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.r.av(SourceFile:5)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.run(SourceFile:17)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bx.run(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.taskgraph.d.a.r.run(SourceFile:7)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.bk.run(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.bk.run(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.m.run(SourceFile:6)
                                                   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.fi(SourceFile:78)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:60)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cv.n(SourceFile:1)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bc.p(SourceFile:33)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.a.run(SourceFile:14)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ar.execute(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.a(SourceFile:216)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.a(SourceFile:184)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.M(SourceFile:130)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.run(SourceFile:15)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ar.execute(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.a(SourceFile:216)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.a(SourceFile:184)
                                                      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(SourceFile:95)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.taskgraph.d.a.w.run(SourceFile:3)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.taskgraph.d.a.m.run(Unknown Source)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.taskgraph.d.a.e.run(SourceFile:17)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.m.run(SourceFile:6)
```

While searching for this in the internet I have found someone saying that it has something to do with the new Google Maps pricing changes that went into effect on July 16, 2018.

I'm not using any routes or map services. I just need to get latitude & longitude every 5 seconds. Should I create an API key and put it somewhere in my code to make my code work again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can not fetch location every 5 seconds from Android Oreo (8.0)

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: google maps pricing has nothing to do with getting gps points